# How can I center these three button literally in the of the page?

Tags: html, css, button, center

How can I center these three buttons so all of them literally dead center of the page? Like if the page is 500 × 500, how can I put them in 250 × 250 place?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <div class="game-ui">
    <div class="row-1">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-0.0" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-0.1" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-0.2" value=" ">
    </div>
    <div class="row-2">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-1.0" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-1.1" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-1.2" value=" ">
    </div><div class="row-3">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-2.0" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-2.1" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-2.2" value=" ">
    </div></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` properties of flex, you can center it to the dead center of `.game-ui`.

```css
.game-ui{ 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  height: 100vh;
}

body{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <div class="game-ui">
    <div class="row-1">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-0.0" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-0.1" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-0.2" value=" ">
    </div>
    <div class="row-2">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-1.0" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-1.1" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-1.2" value=" ">
    </div><div class="row-3">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-2.0" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-2.1" value=" ">
      <input type="button" class="game-btn" id="btn-2.2" value=" ">
    </div></div>
</html>
```

`justify-content` centers it horizontally, and `align-items` centers vertically.